# How to get every other item in a list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list in Mathematica, and I am trying to obtain every other number in the list and store it as a new list.

Currently I have

```
ReadList["file",Number]
```

which reads out the entire list, `{ x1, x2, x3, x4, ... }`; I just want to pick out every other number and store it in a new list, e.g. `{ x1, x3, x5, ... }`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
  yourlist = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
 (* use Span: search for  Span or ;; in Documentation Center *)
 everyotheritemlist = yourlist[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
 (* or use Take *)
 Take[yourlist, {1, -1, 2}]
```

Both give:

```
 {a,c,e,g}
```

Comment: Or the slightly shorter `yourlist[[1 ;; ;; 2]]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Would you also happen to know how to change step size for the Command "ListPlot". It lists in unit steps, and was wondering if there was a way to change this? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @user1200775, pls see the option `DataRange` in the `Options` section of `ListPlot` in the documentation center.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the simplicity of the questions, it is much appreciate

Comment: @user1200775, `ListPlot` also takes a list of `x,y` pairs. So another option is transforming your input data (a list of `y` values) to a list of `x,y` pairs.

Comment: @Brett or even shorter: `yourlist[[;;;;2]]`

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, yes! Thought about `list[[;;-1;;2]]` but it was longer than Brett's suggestion; in the process discovered that things like `list[[]][[;;]][[]][[1;;;;2]][[]][[;;]]` --ad infinitum-- all give the same result! Somehow I missed `;;;;2` !

Comment: @kguler I don't like nested brackets: your comment above almost gave me a seizure.

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like that there are always dozens of creative ways to do it in Mathematica. kguler already gave you the canonical ways, but here's another one:

```
Partition[yourlist, 2]\[Transpose][[1]]

(*
==> {a, c, e, g}
*)
```

By the way: There's a dedicated Mathematica Stackexchange site at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. The Mathematica community is more and more moving in that direction, so you may want to join us there as well.

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
First /@ ReadList["test.dat", {Number, Number}]
```